# Jhipster for production error

Tags: heroku, jhipster

I have a big problem more then 3 days. I generated project with jhipster and after that i want to set new project in production.
I try with Heroku just create new jhipster project, after that i go to:
-heroku login
-jhipster heroku
and automatic go to building application
i get some errors (copy down) and after that i get this message:

Your app should now be live. To view it run
        heroku open
And you can view the logs with this command
        heroku logs --tail
After application modification, redeploy it with
        jhipster heroku
Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!

But when i type heroku open in my browser i have an error:
Application error 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

[heroku open - application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeTtl.png)

This is error when start jhipster heroku:

[Look error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeTtl.png)

Also, i try to put just .war in my Tomcat 7.0 server, but i have trouble when put ./mvnw -Pprod package (have some error like up), and i get .war but my server upload him and dont give me response, i think its problem like up.

I dont have solution for this, thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Errors in deployment log do not look like errors, can you show application logs at startup in Heroku ? Could be that you don't have a database because you did not register a credit card (even for free program).

Comment: Thanks for answer. You think its not errors in this log on picture? Yes, i have logs from startup in Heroku and there i have a 10 exception, like:
- factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
- BeanCreationException
-  ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized,..

Detail for log you can see here: 
https://www.pastiebin.com/5a29cf60ded28

Comment: I try again to create just .war and put on my server Tomcat7 but there i get this error
 
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myappproba-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application logs are pretty clear:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'
```

Your application cannot access database probably because you did not provision one, so the heroku sub generator could not value a jdbc url in application*.yml.

So you have 2 alternatives:

- register a credit card (even for using free account)
- configure a free add-on (e.g. JawsDB MySQL or Heroku Postgresql) in Heroku dashboard.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot man, this is great for me! Problem is i dont use Postgresql, now everything its ok ;) :)